# Converting 2D point to 3D location

Tags: opencv, 2d-3d-conversion

I have a fixed camera with known `cameraMatrix` and `distCoeffs`. I also have a chessboard which is fixed too, and `transform` and `rotation` vector are also calculated using `solvePnP`.

I'm wondering how is possible to get 3D location of a 2D point on the same plane that the chessboard is located, like the picture below:

[image]

One thing for sure is that the **Z** of that point is 0, but how to get **X** and **Y** of that point.

Comment: with your transform and rotation vectors, are you able to explain all of the chessboard corners in 3D?

Comment: if you say that Z will be 0, is it ok for your to just get the plane-coordinates of that point? Like "going 10 cm in red direction and minus 15 cm in green direction?

Comment: @Micka this wont work, because pixels closer to camera represent larger area

Comment: it is easy to get the plane coordinates with a petspective homography. But if you need the 3d points in your camera centered 3d space, you have to transform the plane according to your rotation and translation vectors afterwards.

Comment: Can you provide your expected result of this point coordinates?

Comment: Also the dimensions of the chess board?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve this with 3 simple steps:

**Step 1:**

Compute the 3d direction vector, expressed in the coordinate frame of the camera, of the ray corresponding to the given 2d image point by inverting the camera projection model:

```cpp
std::vector<cv::Point2f> imgPt = {{u,v}}; // Input image point
std::vector<cv::Point2f> normPt;
cv::undistortPoints     (imgPt, normPt, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs);
cv::Matx31f ray_dir_cam(normPt[0].x, normPt[0].y, 1);
// 'ray_dir_cam' is the 3d direction of the ray in camera coordinate frame
// In camera coordinate frame, this ray originates from the camera center at (0,0,0)
```

**Step 2:**

Compute the 3d direction of the vector of this ray in the coordinate frame attached to the chessboard, using the relative pose between the camera and the chessboard:

```cpp
// solvePnP typically gives you 'rvec_cam_chessboard' and 'tvec_cam_chessboard'
// Inverse this pose to get the pose mapping camera coordinates to chessboard coordinates
cv::Matx33f R_cam_chessboard;
cv::Rodrigues(rvec_cam_chessboard, R_cam_chessboard);
cv::Matx33f R_chessboard_cam = R_cam_chessboard.t();
cv::Matx31f t_cam_chessboard = tvec_cam_chessboard;
cv::Matx31f pos_cam_wrt_chessboard = -R_chessboard_cam*t_cam_chessboard;
// Map the ray direction vector from camera coordinates to chessboard coordinates
cv::Matx31f ray_dir_chessboard = R_chessboard_cam * ray_dir_cam;
```

**Step 3:**

Find the desired 3d point by computing the intersection between the 3d ray and the chessboard plane with Z=0:

```cpp
// Expressed in the coordinate frame of the chessboard, the ray originates from the
// 3d position of the camera center, i.e. 'pos_cam_wrt_chessboard', and its 3d
// direction vector is 'ray_dir_chessboard'
// Any point on this ray can be expressed parametrically using its depth 'd':
// P(d) = pos_cam_wrt_chessboard + d * ray_dir_chessboard
// To find the intersection between the ray and the plane of the chessboard, we
// compute the depth 'd' for which the Z coordinate of P(d) is equal to zero
float d_intersection = -pos_cam_wrt_chessboard.val[2]/ray_dir_chessboard.val[2];
cv::Matx31f intersection_point = pos_cam_wrt_chessboard + d_intersection * ray_dir_chessboard;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your case limited to the plains, The simple way is to use Homography.

First [undistort](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga69f2545a8b62a6b0fc2ee060dc30559d) your image. Then use [findHomography](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga4abc2ece9fab9398f2e560d53c8c9780) to calculate the Homography matrix which transform your pixel coordinate (image) to real coordinate (euclidean space e.g. in cm). Something similar to this one:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
//...

//points on undistorted image (in pixel). more is better
vector<Point2f>  src_points = { Point2f(123,321), Point2f(456,654), Point2f(789,987), Point2f(123,321) };
//points on chessboard (e.g. in cm)
vector<Point2f>  dst_points = { Point2f(0, 0), Point2f(12.5, 0), Point2f(0, 16.5), Point2f(12.5, 16.5) }; 
Mat H = findHomography(src_points, dst_points, RANSAC);

//print euclidean coordinate of new point on undistorted image (in pixel)
cout << H * Mat(Point3d(125, 521, 0)) << endl;
```

Comment: I did what you said: 

vector<Point2f> corners, vector<Point2f> objectPoints2d;
findChessboardCorners(img, patternSize, corners);
calcChessboardCorners(patternSize, squareSize, objectPoints2d);
chessboardHomography = findHomography(corners, objectPoints2d, RANSAC);

Comment: it does not work, and the coordinate it returns is not correct

Comment: even if you multiply the homography matrix with the pixel which is located on chessboard [0,0,0] it will return [-192, -129, 0.33]

Comment: @EBAG do you undistore image first? check objectPoints2d be correct. Event print and check them manually.